# Simple camel routing from to

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I have a fundamental question regarding routing in Camel.  Assuming I have this following route:

```
from(amq:MyQueue).process("jmsToHttp4").to("http4://dummyhost:8080").to("file://out/MyFolder");
```

Assuming that the http4-Response is just a String "Your Response".  As far as I understood the documentation, "Your Response" can be retrieved through:

```
exchange.getOut().getBody()
```

Lets say that I only want to write "file://out/MyFolder", only if the reponse contains the word "Response".  How can I achive this?

One more question:
If I want to write a test in a spring environment, how can I mock the response with "Your Response positive test" and "Your negative test"?  Somehow I need to be able to write the response strings in the exchange.out.body right?

Thank you,

Hadi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to declare a `.filter(body().contains("Response"))` right after the HTTP call.

As for the test, you might use the mock component that offers you ways of processing the exchange and also asserting whatever you need when the message hits your mock endpoint.

There is actually some alternatives to test... I'm used to declaring the endpoints in the properties file and using the key in the class, e.g. `.to("{{my.http.target}}")`. Thus, in this case, in the test environment (dedicated properties file) you'd replace your http4 with mock.

In my opinion, it is cleaner and requires less control of the context when writing tests, mainly in big/complex applications. On the other hand, this might affect code readability.

But if you prefer to keep declaration in your Java class, you'll have to intercept the http4 call in the test env, then divert it to your mock endpoint.

I hope it's helpful.